# Should I spend my summer as an independent researcher?

Tags: research-process, masters, independent-researcher

I am a Masters student at a mid tier school (and perhaps getting dangerously close to low tier for my field specifically). I am planning on applying to PhD programs this coming Fall. I applied for close to two dozen internships for this summer, both at research labs and in industry. I was rejected from all of them. Needless to say this was pretty emotionally devastating, and made me question my career choice altogether.

My options for this summer are to get a job, which is not related to my research field, or use my savings to self-fund research.

On one hand this seems like a completely crazy idea, but in my field I don't need any serious resources beyond a powerful computer to do research, so I should be perfectly capable. My past research has essentially been independent with light guidance from a professor at my university.

And for context, I have one conference publication as first author, and I am finishing up a project from this last semester which I expect to be publishable in the near future.

Comment: Have you checked PhD application deadlines for "this coming Fall"? Or do you mean Fall 2018?

Comment: Ah I worded that badly. I mean I will be sending applications this Fall. So my expected start date would be Fall 2018.

Comment: Why not do both - part time work and do some independent research?

Comment: This is a very personal decision, which of course must be partly based on your financial situation.  One great thing to do in the summer prior to writing grad school applications in the fall is to do some GRE subject test prep. // If you don't need the money, and you think you'd be able to make good academic progress over the summer, then by all means work on your academics. // It is important not to take the rejections personally.  Job hunting and internship hunting is a tremendous crap shoot. // You might be able to rescue the question (which is likely to get closed) ...

Comment: by asking for help in Academia Meta to make the question less about you and more about the situation.  I'm not making a specific suggestion how to do it because that is not my forte.  But I have a hunch this question could be saved.

Comment: I have been trying to delete my account for over a week. Please delete it for good.

I have emailed your developers back and forth for over a week. This is ridiculous.